# Makefile: different flags for similar files

Tags: makefile, compiler-flags

I have several files to compile: `one.f` `two.f` ... `ten.f`

Some need to be compiled with different flags. For example, from `one.f` to `five.f` need to be compiled with `ifort -O` and `six.f` to `ten.f` need to be compiled with `ifort -O2`.

How can I make two implicit rules that know which files compile with which flags? Or any way in which to group then together so I don't have to specify file by file.

Similarly:

Some depend on the module `mod.f` and others don't. Can I specify this dependency without doing it in a file by file basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely specify dependencies on a per-target basis but you do need a way of specifying the right targets (likely explicitly) though not necessarily manually if you can construct the list some other way (or have it in a variable already).

The line `one.o two.o three.o four.o five.o: mod.f` will add that as a prerequisite to those targets (for whatever rule actually builds those targets.

Similarly you can assign [6.11 Target-specific variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) and use those.

```
one.o two.o three.o four.o five.o: FFLAGS+=-O
six.o seven.o eight.o nine.o ten.o: FFLAGS+=-O2
```

will add the right optimization flag to the built-in `%.o: %.f` (or anything else that uses `$(FFLAGS)`.